# Como restringir para que não se coloque uma data maior e depois uma data menor usando o Calendar Restrict?

Tags: java, primefaces, calendar, jee

Boa noite! eis meu problema:

Estou fazendo uma tela que possui dois calendários:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O programa vai me retornar uma lista que compreende o intervalo entre duas datas. Uma data é do primeiro calendário, e a outra do segundo calendário.

Porém, meu código abaixo não está funcionando.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Sistema de Integração Moriah</title>
    <style type="text/css">
#painel {
    font-family: geneva, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

#form {
    padding-left: 60px;
}

</style>
</h:head>
<body>
    <ui:decorate template="menubardecorate.xhtml"></ui:decorate>
    <p:panel header="Selecione como deseja as Ordens de Serviço" id="painel">
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:panelGrid columns="5">
                <p:outputLabel value="Datas da OS:" />
                <p:outputLabel for="de" value="De:" />
                <p:calendar id="de" value="#{ListaOsBean.dataDe}" mindate="01/01/10" maxdate="" update="ate" />
                <p:outputLabel for="ate" value="Até:" />
                <p:calendar id="ate" value="{ListaOsBean.dataAte}" mindate="#{ListaOsBean.getDataDe()}" maxdate="" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

O `"#{ListaOsBean.dataDe}"` não está recebendo a data passada pelo usuário, e não está retornando para o outro `<p:calendar/>` em `mindate="#{ListaOsBean.getDataDe()}"`.

O que quero é que, assim que clicar na data do primeiro calendário, só fique disponíveis no segundo calendário, os números após a data que selecionei no primeiro. Desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Bean está assim:

```
package br.com.moriahitg.bean;

import br.com.moriahitg.dao.SZA990DAO;
import br.com.moriahitg.modelo.SZA990;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ListaOsBean {

    List<SZA990> list = new ArrayList<SZA990>();
    Date dataDe;
    String dataDeS, dataAteS;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String addOSNaListaPorCliente() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String a1_cod = (String) session.getAttribute("A1_COD");
        SZA990DAO szadao = new SZA990DAO();
        list = szadao.getOSPorCliente(a1_cod);
        return "/listaDeOSs.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public List<SZA990> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<SZA990> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public Date getDataDe() {
        return dataDe;
    }

    public void setDataDe(Date dataDe) {
        this.dataDe = dataDe;
    }

//  public Date getDataAte() {
//      return dataAte;
//  }

//  public void setDataAte(Date dataAte) {
//      this.dataAte = dataAte;
//  }

    public String getDataDeS() {
        return dataDeS;
    }

    public void setDataDeS(String dataDeS) {
        this.dataDeS = dataDeS;
    }

    public String getDataAteS() {
        return dataAteS;
    }

    public void setDataAteS(String dataAteS) {
        this.dataAteS = dataAteS;
    }

}
```

Devo usar algum listener, ou ajax? Agradeço desde já pela resposta! Procurei e não encontrei algo específico.

Comment: Bem, a solução foi usar o listener. O método "noClick()" dentro do <p:ajax> adiciona o conteúdo do campo na variável dataDe. Por sua vez, esta variável retorna para o segundo calendário em "maxdate" desta forma: maxdate="#{ListaOsBean.getDataDe()}".

Answer (score 1):

Usa ajax, quando o campo perder o foco você chama o listener e invoca o metodo set para definir a data inicial, depois no segundo field defina que a data minima seja o valor setado pelo listener do date anterior.

```
<p:calendar id="dataInicial" value="#{bean.dataInicial}">
  <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.setDataInicial}" update="toDate" />
</p:calendar>

<p:calendar id="dataFinal" value="#{bean.dataFinal}"  mindate="#{bean.getDataInicial}"/>
```